# Workload setting on Kubernetes for high availability

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I am new on kubernetes, I created a k8s cluster which contain two worker node - Node-AZ1 and Node-AZ2.

For my objective, I would like to set two pods/deploys with same web application image for High availability setting.
i.e.

```
K8S Cluster -> Worker Node: Node-AZ1 
                    -> Pod: Backend-App-AZ1-{id} 
                            -> Deploy: Backend-App-AZ1 (Backend App Image v1.0.0)
            -> Worker Node:  Node-AZ2 
                    -> Pod: Backend-App-AZ2-{id} 
                            -> Deploy: Backend-App-AZ2 (Backend App Image v1.0.0)
```

In k8s service setting, it contain the type - LoadBalancer, but seem that it is not proxy type load balancer. In my question, I would like to find a tool/config setting that can be the proxy type load balancer for proxying the request to AZ1 and AZ2 averagely.
E.G.
Post Request to : http://www.sample.com/api
the load balancer will proxy the request to either the api service on workload:Backend-App-AZ1 or  the api service on workload:Backend-App-AZ2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend using the Nginx ingress if you can use it and handling the traffic using it

So traffic will flow like

```
internet -> ingress > K8s service > Deployments > PODs
```

You can checkout : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/

Or daemon set : https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/deployments/daemon-set/nginx-ingress.yaml

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try nginx ingress :)